# $�a �$I��"I�$�... for PNG image - Vue/Node/Express | How do I display an image that I sent from a Node.js server to a client Vue app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, vue.js, display

Using Node/Express, I have the following route:

```js
app.get('/get-image', function(req, res) {

  ...
  
  
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', account.profileImg));
})
```

In my client Vue app, I am trying to display the image that I am receiving from the server.. Currently I am sending the file to the console and I get these weird characters:

04f\u0001���@7�\u000f�T�n���_�\u0004\f\u0002# .... and so on ... a very long string

The header says that it is type "content-type
:
"image/png" " which is great because I am trying to display an image.

What do I need to do to transform this string into a viewable image? Something that I can pass to my Vue component in the form of an  HTML tag.

Any tips/advice in the right direction would be incredibly helpful!

[04f\u0001���@7�\u000f�T�n���_�\u0004\f\u0002#](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7KbC.jpg)

Comment: The generic answer is: Set the `scr` attribute of an `<img>` element to the URL. Show your code.

Comment: You need to set correct mime headers i.e. `content type`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to send the image data as a base64 endcoded string using [btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa), the set the image's `src` attribute using the encoded string from the response:

```
<img src=`data:image/png;base64,${data}`/>
```

Otherwise, you can also return the response image from Express like:

```
let image = new Buffer(imageData, 'base64');

res.writeHead(200, {
  'Content-Type': 'image/png',
  'Content-Length': image.length
});
res.end(image);
```

Comment: And why would you use an Ajax request to fetch `data` from the server, encode it as base64 on the client, write that to an `<img src="">` attribute, let the browser parse it and convert it back from base64 so it can display the result? That's an *extremely* wasteful and round-about way of doing `<img src="/get-image">`, I think.

Comment: Where's the improvement? All that does is load the superfluous wasteful calculation on the server instead of on the client. My question was not about *where* to waste processor cycles for useless conversions. My question was what's wrong with doing `<img src="/get-image">`.

Comment: There's a point for using `src="data:image/png;base64,..."` attributes, and it's either when you save HTTP requests by compiling static images right into the HTML source - a performance optimization in situations where transferring multiple small images would create noticeable overhead - or when you calculate images dynamically somehow and all you have is a byte array, not a URL. On the other hand, base64-encoding on the fly an actual, server-located image file that has an actual URL works, but it's not exactly sensible. The browser will be *much* more efficient in retrieving it natively.

Comment: @Tomalak why would I do that? Because I  didn't know how.. Thanks for your suggestion!